# bootstrap make panel on phone 100% of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="height:40px">
...
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to have a panel in a modal dialog use the whole width of the screen when on a phone but on an ipad or higher I want it to use about 90% of the width.

The problem is that the responsive sizes are typically changed by using classes such as col-xs-12 which won't put the size to the edge of the screen.

I have may panel set as:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="height:40px">
...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So do you have an update?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use media query like this one

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #divId {
        width or max-width: 90%;
    }

}
```

another good option is just using the full width of the screen, and include the div inside a container. The container will be centered in the screen with margin, padding etc... You can edit with a media queries this parameters so they only show at that desired screen size.

aks me for any additional question